# Implementing my own Read, Write, Open, Close functions for an Ext2 file system

Tags: c, ext2

Cheers,
So basically I need to create functions named my_open, my_read, my_write, and my_close that manipulate an Ext2 file system image. This all needs to be done in C (the only language I know).
I have written some code that prints all the directories and files stemming from the root directory within the file system but I want to be able to use this code to manipulate the file system. Here is my code:

---

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "/include/ext2.h"

#define BASE_OFFSET 1024
#define BLOCK_OFFSET(block) (BASE_OFFSET+(block-1)*block_size)
#define NAMELEN     255

unsigned int block_size = 0;

void read_inode(int, int, const struct ext2_group_desc*, struct ext2_inode*);
void read_dir(int, struct ext2_inode*, const struct ext2_group_desc*, char *);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char imgname[BASE_OFFSET];
  struct ext2_super_block super_block;
  struct ext2_group_desc block_group;
  struct ext2_inode inode;
  int fd;

  if (argc > 1)
    strcpy(imgname, argv[1]);
  else
    fprintf(stderr, " Command Usage: step1 %s ", imgname);

  if ((fd = open(imgname, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: step1 %s", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
  }

  fd = open(imgname, O_RDONLY);
  if(lseek(fd, BASE_OFFSET, SEEK_SET) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr,"unable to seek\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  /* read super-block */

  lseek(fd, BASE_OFFSET, SEEK_SET);
  read(fd, &super_block, sizeof(super_block));

   block_size = 1024 << super_block.s_log_block_size;

  /* read group descriptor */

  lseek(fd, BASE_OFFSET + block_size, SEEK_SET);
  read(fd, &block_group, sizeof(block_group));

  /* show entries in the root directory */

  read_inode(fd, 2, &block_group, &inode);   /* read inode 2 (root directory) */
  read_dir(fd, &inode, &block_group, "/");

  close(fd);
  exit(0);
}

 void read_inode(int fd, int inode_no, const struct ext2_group_desc *block_group, struct ext2_inode *inode)
{
  lseek(fd, BLOCK_OFFSET(block_group->bg_inode_table)+(inode_no-1)*sizeof(struct ext2_inode),
    SEEK_SET);
  read(fd, inode, sizeof(struct ext2_inode));
}

void read_dir(int fd, struct ext2_inode *inode, const struct ext2_group_desc *block_group, char *prefix)
{
  void *block;

  if (S_ISDIR(inode->i_mode)) {
    struct ext2_dir_entry_2 *entry;
     unsigned int size = 0;
    char *tmpprefix;

    //prefix = malloc (siozeof(char) * BASE_OFFSET);                                                                                        


    if ((block = malloc(block_size)) == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Not enough Memory.\n");
       close(fd);
       exit(1);
     }

    lseek(fd, BLOCK_OFFSET(inode->i_block[0]), SEEK_SET);
    read(fd, block, block_size);
    entry = (struct ext2_dir_entry_2 *) block;  /* first entry in the directory */
       //entry (entry->inode == NULL)                                                                                                       
    while((size < inode->i_size) && entry->inode) {
      char file_name[NAMELEN+1];
      memcpy(file_name, entry->name, entry->name_len);
      file_name[entry->name_len] = 0;     /* append null character */
      if (*file_name != '.')
      //if (strcmp(file_name,".") == 0 || strcmp(file_name,"..")== 0) continue;                                                             
      if (entry->file_type == 2) {
        printf("%10u %s%s/\n", entry->inode, prefix,file_name);
        read_inode(fd, entry->inode, block_group, inode);
        tmpprefix = (char *)malloc(strlen(file_name)+strlen(prefix)+2);
        sprintf(tmpprefix, "%s%s/",prefix,file_name);
        read_dir(fd, inode, block_group, tmpprefix);
        free(tmpprefix);
      }
      else {
        printf("%10u %s%s\n", entry->inode, prefix, file_name);
      }
      entry = (void*) entry + entry->rec_len;
      size += entry->rec_len;
    }
    free(block);
  }
}


/*                                                                                                                                          
 my_open(char *fn, int mode)                                                                                                                 
 {                                                                                                                                           

 }                                                                                                                                           

 my_close(char *fn, descriptor)                                                                                                              
 {                                                                                                                                           

 }                                                                                                                                           

 my_read()                                                                                                                                   
 {                                                                                                                                           

 }        
 my_write()                                                                                                                                  
 {                                                                                                                                           

 }                                                                                                                                           

*/
```

Here is my Header file with the structures:

```
/*
   __u32     * Structure of the super block
*/
#include <linux/types.h>

#define EXT2_NDIR_BLOCKS  12
#define EXT2_IND_BLOCK    EXT2_NDIR_BLOCKS
#define EXT2_DIND_BLOCK  (EXT2_IND_BLOCK + 1)
#define EXT2_TIND_BLOCK  (EXT2_DIND_BLOCK + 1)
#define EXT2_N_BLOCKS    (EXT2_TIND_BLOCK + 1)
#define EXT2_NAME_LEN     255

struct ext2_super_block
{
  __u32 s_inodes_count;         /* Inodes count */
  __u32 s_blocks_count;         /* Blocks count */
  __u32 s_r_blocks_count;       /* Reserved blocks count */
  __u32 s_free_blocks_count;    /* Free blocks count */
  __u32 s_free_inodes_count;    /* Free inodes */
  __u32 s_first_data_block;     /* First Data Block */
  __u32 s_log_block_size;       /* Block size */
  __u32 s_log_frag_size;        /* Fragment size */
  __u32 s_blocks_per_group;     /* # Blocks per group */
  __s32 s_frags_per_group;      /* # Fragments per group */
  __u32 s_inodes_per_group;     /* # Inodes per group */
  __u32 s_mtime;                /* Mount time */
  __u32 s_wtime;                /* Write time */
  __u16 s_mnt_count;            /* Mount count */
  __s16 s_max_mnt_count;        /* Maximal mount count */
  __u16 s_magic;                /* Magic signature */
  __u16 s_state;                /* File system state */
  __u16 s_errors;               /* Behaviour when detecting errors */
  __u16 s_minor_rev_level;      /* minor revision level */
  __u32 s_lastcheck;            /* time of last check */
  __u32 s_checkinterval;        /* max. time between checks */
  __u32 s_creator_os;           /* OS */
  __u32 s_rev_level;            /* Revision level */
  __u16 s_def_resuid;           /* Default uid for reserved blocks */
  __u16 s_def_resgid;           /* Default gid for reserved blocks */
  __u32 s_first_ino;            /* First non-reserved inode */
  __u16 s_inode_size;           /* size of inode structure */
  __u16 s_block_group_nr;       /* block group # of this superblock */
  __u32 s_feature_compat;       /* compatible feature set */
  __u32 s_feature_incompat;     /* incompatible feature set */

/*
  __u32     * Structure of the super block
*/
#include <linux/types.h>

#define EXT2_NDIR_BLOCKS  12
#define EXT2_IND_BLOCK    EXT2_NDIR_BLOCKS
#define EXT2_DIND_BLOCK  (EXT2_IND_BLOCK + 1)
#define EXT2_TIND_BLOCK  (EXT2_DIND_BLOCK + 1)
#define EXT2_N_BLOCKS    (EXT2_TIND_BLOCK + 1)
#define EXT2_NAME_LEN     255

struct ext2_super_block
{
  __u32 s_inodes_count;         /* Inodes count */
  __u32 s_blocks_count;         /* Blocks count */
  __u32 s_r_blocks_count;       /* Reserved blocks count */
  __u32 s_free_blocks_count;    /* Free blocks count */
  __u32 s_free_inodes_count;    /* Free inodes */
  __u32 s_first_data_block;     /* First Data Block */
  __u32 s_log_block_size;       /* Block size */
  __u32 s_log_frag_size;        /* Fragment size */
  __u32 s_blocks_per_group;     /* # Blocks per group */
  __s32 s_frags_per_group;      /* # Fragments per group */
  __u32 s_inodes_per_group;     /* # Inodes per group */
  __u32 s_mtime;                /* Mount time */
  __u32 s_wtime;                /* Write time */
  __u16 s_mnt_count;            /* Mount count */
  __s16 s_max_mnt_count;        /* Maximal mount count */
  __u16 s_magic;                /* Magic signature */
  __u16 s_state;                /* File system state */
  __u16 s_errors;               /* Behaviour when detecting errors */
  __u16 s_minor_rev_level;      /* minor revision level */
  __u32 s_lastcheck;            /* time of last check */
  __u32 s_checkinterval;        /* max. time between checks */
  __u32 s_creator_os;           /* OS */
  __u32 s_rev_level;            /* Revision level */
  __u16 s_def_resuid;           /* Default uid for reserved blocks */
  __u16 s_def_resgid;           /* Default gid for reserved blocks */
  __u32 s_first_ino;            /* First non-reserved inode */
  __u16 s_inode_size;           /* size of inode structure */
  __u16 s_block_group_nr;       /* block group # of this superblock */
  __u32 s_feature_compat;       /* compatible feature set */
  __u32 s_feature_incompat;     /* incompatible feature set */
  __u32 s_feature_ro_compat;    /* readonly-compatible feature set */
  __u8 s_uuid[16];              /* 128-bit uuid for volume */
  char s_volume_name[16];       /* volume name */
  char s_last_mounted[64];      /* directory where last mounted */
  __u32 s_algorithm_usage_bitmap;       /* For compression */
  __u8 s_prealloc_blocks;       /* Nr of blocks to try to preallocate */
  __u8 s_prealloc_dir_blocks;   /* Nr to preallocate for dirs */
  __u16 s_padding1;
  __u32 s_reserved[204];        /* Padding to the end of the block */
};

struct ext2_group_desc
{
  __u32 bg_block_bitmap;        /* Blocks bitmap block */
  __u32 bg_inode_bitmap;        /* Inodes bitmap block */
  __u32 bg_inode_table;         /* Inodes table block */
  __u16 bg_free_blocks_count;   /* Free blocks count */
  __u16 bg_free_inodes_count;   /* Free inodes count */
  __u16 bg_used_dirs_count;     /* Directories count */
  __u16 bg_pad;
  __u32 bg_reserved[3];
};

struct ext2_inode
{
  __u16 i_mode;                 /* File mode */
  __u16 i_uid;                  /* Low 16 bits of Owner Uid */
  __u32 i_size;                 /* Size in bytes */
  __u32 i_atime;                /* Access time */
  __u32 i_ctime;                /* Creation time */
  __u32 i_mtime;                /* Modification time */
  __u32 i_dtime;                /* Deletion Time */
  __u16 i_gid;                  /* Low 16 bits of Group Id */
  __u16 i_links_count;          /* Links count */
  __u32 i_blocks;               /* Blocks count */
  __u32 i_flags;                /* File flags */
  union
  {
    struct {
       __u32 l_i_reserved1;
    } linux1;
    struct {
      __u32 h_i_translator;
    } hurd1;
    struct {
      __u32 m_i_reserved1;
    } masix1;
  } osd1;                       /* OS dependent 1 */
  __u32 i_block[EXT2_N_BLOCKS]; /* Pointers to blocks */
  __u32 i_generation;           /* File version (for NFS) */
  __u32 i_file_acl;             /* File ACL */
  __u32 i_dir_acl;              /* Directory ACL */
  __u32 i_faddr;                /* Fragment address */
  union {
    struct {
      __u8 l_i_frag;            /* Fragment number */
      __u8 l_i_fsize;           /* Fragment size */
      __u16 i_pad1;
      __u16 l_i_uid_high;       /* these 2 fields    */
      __u16 l_i_gid_high;       /* were reserved2[0] */
      __u32 l_i_reserved2;
    } linux2;
    struct {
      __u8 h_i_frag;            /* Fragment number */
      __u8 h_i_fsize;           /* Fragment size */
      __u16 h_i_mode_high;
      __u16 h_i_uid_high;
      __u16 h_i_gid_high;
      __u32 h_i_author;
    } hurd2;
    struct {
      __u8 m_i_frag;            /* Fragment number */
      __u8 m_i_fsize;           /* Fragment size */
      __u16 m_pad1;
      __u32 m_i_reserved2[2];
    } masix2;
  } osd2;
};

struct ext2_dir_entry_2
{
  __u32 inode;                  /* Inode number */
  __u16 rec_len;                /* Directory entry length */
  __u8 name_len;                /* Name length */
  __u8 file_type;
  char name[EXT2_NAME_LEN];     /* File name */
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use [libext2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e2fsprogs/)

Comment: What part of libext2 would I use specifically?

Comment: It is up to you to define how and what. It is a library to manipulate ext2 file systems. We don't know what you want to do with it (and on which OS or hardware). You should explain that by editing your question. Generally, on Linux, people are *mounting* file systems. Why don't you do that?